# Copying first n items of a dictionary into another dictionary

Tags: python

This is a simple question but I am unable to code this in python. I want to copy first n items ( supposedly 100 ) i.e both the values and keys into another empty dictionary. I'll give a more clear picture of this.  I created a dictionary and sorted it using OrderedDict. My code for sorting it is :

ordP = OrderedDict(reversed(sorted(wcP.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])))

Here ordP is the ordered dictionary I got. This is in descending order. And my original dictionary is wcP. I want to put the first 100 values of ordP i.e the first 100 maximum values of ordP ( sorted according to the keys ) in a new dictionary.

Comment: Keys in Python dictionaries are not ordered. Do you want 100 random ones or the first 100 after sorting by something?

Comment: I have sorted them using OrderedDict. But the first 100 do not have key values from 1-100.

Comment: OrderedDict doesn't do what you think it does. It's ordered based on the point of insertion, not on how the keys compare. It is not, for example, a `SortedMap` from Java.

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries aren't ordered, but if you just want a random selection:

```
new_values = dict(your_values.items()[:n])
```

Or, for those obsessed with laziness:

```
import itertools
new_values = dict(itertools.islice(your_values.iteritems(), n))
```

If there's a particular sort you want to impose, define a key function that takes the key and value. People usually do lambdas, but there's no reason you can't use a full function.

```
def example_key_func((key, value)):
    return key * value

new_dict = dict(sorted(your_values.items(), key=example_key_func)[:n])
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine :)

Comment: I tried but the answer isnt what I want. Also its not showing the top 100 values. I'll try to give a more clear picture of what Ive done. I created a dictionary and sorted it using OrderedDict. My code for sorting it is :    ordP = OrderedDict(reversed(sorted(wcP.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])))           Here ordP is the ordered dictionary I got. This is in descending order. And my original dictionary is wcP. I want to put the first 100 values of ordP i.e the first 100 maximum values of ordP ( sorted according to the keys ) in a new dictionary

Comment: @user3848891 - If you want to clarify your question please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29879607/edit) it instead of burying important details in comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 100
assert len(d.keys()) >= n
dic100 = {k:v for k,v in list(d.items())[:n]}
```

Comment: @user3848891 Select the answer by jwilner as the correct answer. It's much better than mine.